# jQuery's on change event not working on chrome nexus 7

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I am using on change function on my project using rails 4 and turbolinks. It is working fine in my web browser but when i test this on nexus 7 Android 5.1.1 it does not work. 
following is my code.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= image_attributes.file_field :photo, :style => "display:none", :class => "update-file", :data => {:thumbnail => image_attributes.index}, accept: 'image/png,image/jpeg' %>
```

common.js

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.update-file', function(event) {
return console.log('1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When `change` is not firing properly, you could try to additionally use a different event like `blur`.

```
$(document.body).on('change blur', '.update-file', function(event) {
    return console.log('1');
});
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it is also not working on nexus 7 chrome. It works fine on other devices and on my system's browser.

Comment: Sorry to hear... It would be interesting to see, if there are any error-messages on the nexus-browser. You can see them, if you connect your nexus to your PC via adb, than open Chrome-Browser on your PC and you can finally see exactly what is going on, by entering `chrome://inspect` in chrome's address-bar. Here is an explanation: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: I am using browserstack and it doesn't display any error on the console. I have tried tried different selectors i.e.
$(document).on('change', '.update-file', function(event){console.log('1');});
and
$(document).on('change blur', '.update-file', function(event){console.log('1');});
and
$(document.body).on('change blur', '.update-file', function(event){console.log('1');});
and
$('.update-file').on('change', function(event){console.log('1');});
all these work fine on other devise but not on nexus 7.